# Object has no method writeHead

Tags: node.js

Example from "socket.IO Real-time Web Application Developement" from Rohit Rai. This is the 2nd example about routing request :

```
var http =  require("http");
var url =  require("url");

var route = {
        routes:{},
        for: function(path,handler){
            this.routes[path] = handler;
        }
};

route.for("/start", function(response,request){
        response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write("Hello2");
        response.end();
    }
);

route.for("/finish", function(response,request){
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write("Goodbye2");
        response.end();
    }
);

function onRequest(request,response){
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    console.log("Request for: " + pathname + " received");

    if(typeof route.routes[pathname] === 'function'){
        route.routes[pathname](request,response);

   }
    else{
       response.writeHead(404,{"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
       response.end("404 Not Found!");
   }
};

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(9999);
console.log("Server has started");
```

Console says that server has started, 404 works, but as soon as i try start or finish, i get an errormessage in my console: 
refers to resources.js:12
TypeError Object # has no method 'writeHead' ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You swapped the request and response parameters in the /start and /finish lines.

```
route.for("/start", function(request,response){
route.for("/finish", function(request,response){
```

That should fix the error.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!! spent hours to this one., reread earlier examples many times and drunk at least 1 liter of black coffee. Did not help, your "easy" answer did the job.Thanks!!!  need 5 minutes to wait before i can set this as accepted answer...